# TV capacitor 54j 6kv swc

Tags: capacitor, tv

My television (the brand is Philips) died and I'm trying to save it, 
When I had open it I had see a dead capacitor (54j 6kv swc), the most similar I saw was on Ali express with (54j 6kv), I don't know if it will do the tricks and the seller have bad reviews. 
I don't really understand the meaning of this kind of notations with my basic notions of electronic, is their an tutorial to understand this notation or a capacitor that can work in place of the dead on or a good website where I can buy it?

Thanks for reading this and I hope you have a great day.

[image: dead capacitor 54j 6kv swc]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't look broken.

The white stuff is glue.

That part is either a ceramic capacitor (which would crumble if it were broken, but has no liquids inside) or it is a transient voltage suppressor (which also has no liquids, and would either burn or shatter if it were bad.) So, I don't think this part is the problem.

If that is a capacitor, then it would be rated 54 picofarads (54j) and for use at up to 6000 volts (6kV.)

Answer (score 2):

THat is a typical MOV for lightning protection on the AC line. Since there are no signs of heat, ignore that.

If by "TV", I assume LCD vs CRT,  since you mentioned reviews.
If you say "dead" I assume, no lights at all, then inspect PS board for a fuse and bulged large electrolytic caps, and get same or equiv low ESR type.  The web ought to have photos of repairs on google images for your TV.

If you mean by you mean "no video",  then suspect the CFL's or DC-DC board.

Report anything slightly bulged on lid of cylindrical can. near magnetics on power supply. THat's a normal failure mode from heat and low quality part.

Comment: It was the seller of the replacement part who had bad reviews, not the TV itself.